# Multiplying for loop inputs in Python3

Tags: python, list, for-loop, int

I am coding a small program in Python3 that calculates the network availability.

According to my Data Communications class, you determine your network availability by multiplying the availability of each device in your network.

**For example:** There are 3 devices in your network. Device 1 has an availability of .67. Device 2 has an availability of .94. Device 3 has an availability of .79. Then you multiply the availabilities: .67 * .94 * .79 = .498 network availability.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
# Network Availability
# by Nicholas Zachariah

numDev = int(input("How many devices do you have? ")) # number of devices
print(f"There are {numDev} devices.")
devList = list(range(1, numDev+1)) # device list


for device in devList:
    ava = input(f"What is the availability of device number {device}? ") # availability
```

From here, I would like to store each availability input, and then multiply each device's availability and print the overall network's availability, but I am having trouble fulfilling this task as I cannot figure out how to individually store each device's availability. Can anyone help?

**PS**
In simple terms, I am looking for the network's Total Availability.

Comment: Might help to use a `dict` here in the form of `{device: availability}`, then you can access all the availability by using `dict.values()`

Comment: If the name of the device does not matter, just fill a list with values then multiply elements each other.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I like that idea. Let me try to figure that out from here on my own. If not, may I come back and ask for some more help? I will also let you know if I was able to figure it out.

Comment: @NicholasZachariah You're always free to ask questions!  If you do manage to solve your own problem, I'd suggest posting an answer to your question.  When you're able to accept an answer, pick whichever one solves your problem *best* with the ✅

Comment: Thank you. I will make sure to do so.

Comment: I see you're still learning python, I'd suggest reading through [the python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) that is part of the python official documentation.  This will be a great primer to start learning many different parts of the language.  There is also [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) which provides MANY built-in modules to reduce the need for re-inventing the wheel and also [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html) to help you with any unfamiliar keywords, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that you're defining ava from the input given. In this case the input given is supposed to be an int, so ava will be an int. You need to specify that ava is a list beforehand, so that you can use .append() to append the input value.

After that you can loop through the ava list and multiply up to the result:

```
# Network Availability
# by Nicholas Zachariah

numDev = int(input("How many devices do you have? ")) # number of devices
print(f"There are {numDev} devices.")
devList = list(range(1, numDev+1)) # device list
ava = []

for device in devList:
    ava.append(int(input(f"What is the availability of device number {device}? ")))

print (ava)
TotalAvailability = 1

for device in ava:
    TotalAvailability *=device

print( TotalAvailability)
```

Comment: This is what helped me the most. However, I am stuck on TotalAvailability, You have it set equal to 1, but then pretty much have "1 = 1 * device" (TotalAvailability = TotalAvailability * device). Can you explain how that works please?

Comment: Run through it in your head: You first start with Total = 1, then Total = 1*device, which means Total = device_1, next run you get Total = device_1*device_2... etc. !

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict for the values.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import operator
from functools import reduce

numDev = int(input("How many devices do you have? ")) # number of devices
print("There are {} devices.".format(numDev))

devList = list(range(1, numDev+1)) # device list
ava = {}

for device in devList:
    ava[device] = float(input("What is the availability of device number {}? ".format(device))) #add to dict

print("{:.2f}".format(reduce(operator.mul, ava.values(), 1)))

>>>How many devices do you have? 2
>>>There are 2 devices.
>>>What is the availability of device number 1? .65
>>>What is the availability of device number 2? .66
>>>0.43
```

Comment: As I am sure your code is valid, I am not familiar enough with imports and how to use them yet. I will definitely look at your code and work with it though so I can start practicing! I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. Imports can be intimidating, but really all they are is a way to give you access to methods which are not available without the import. For example, there is a module called "functools". It has a method which I needed called "reduce", so the import statement says to import just the one method and not the whole module. If you import the whole module, like I did with operator, you need to specify that the item belongs to the module. Hence, "operator.mul".

Comment: I'd like to point out `functools` is in [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) so you don't need to install anything additional.

Comment: This is not what he is looking for, he wants to 'print the overall network's availability'

Comment: @AdamDadvar I believe you misunderstood the question. "then multiply each device's availability and print the overall network's availability, but I am having trouble fulfilling this task as I cannot figure out how to individually store each device's availability."

Comment: @AdamDadvar after looking at your response I can see you understand the question, but failed to noticed that I've also provided the answer.

Comment: @KuboMD You're right there, did not recognise that code at all, reduce with mul is a really unreadable way to write what should be a very simple task no?

Comment: @AdamDadvar Sure

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand (not what everyone else has inferred) you want to find the *total* network availability, in other words the product of all availabilities.

In order to individually store the availability you can use one of the many iterable objects in python, the simplest one is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). A list is a data structure that holds multiple elements (not necessarily of the same type).

In order to achieve what you want to accomplish you need the following:

```
# Network Availability
# by Nicholas Zachariah

numDev = int(input("How many devices do you have? ")) # number of devices
print(f"There are {numDev} devices.")
devList = list(range(1, numDev+1)) # device list

availability_list = list()
for device in devList:
    ava = input(f"What is the availability of device number {device}? ") # availability
    availability_list.append(ava)
curr_avail = availability_list.pop()
for avail in availability_list:
    curr_avail = curr_avail*avail
```

For example, when you enter 0.8, 0.7, and 0.6

```
availability_list = [0.8, 0.7, 0.6]
curr_avail = availability_list.pop()
for avail in availability_list:
    curr_avail = curr_avail*avail

curr_avail
>>> 0.33599999999999997
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael King had a great answer, and I marked it as correct. Here is my new code based on his answer. I just kind of organized it a little more and used a round function so the final result doesn't have ten decimal places.

```
netAva = 1 # Network Availability
ava = [] # List of each device's availability

numDev = int(input("How many devices do you have? ")) # number of devices
print(f"There are {numDev} devices.")
devList = list(range(1, numDev+1)) # device list

for device in devList:
    ava.append(float(input(f"What is the availability of device number     {device}? "))) # availability

for device in ava:
    netAva *= device

netAva = round(netAva, 3)

print(f"{netAva} is your network's availability.")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a list before the for loop add use list.append()

```
numDev = int(input('How many devices do you have? '))
print(f'There are {numDev} devices.')
devList = list(range(1, numDev+1))
avaList = []

for device in devlist:
    avaList.append(input(f'What is the availability of device number {device}? '))
```

Comment: This does not address the question at all.